# In C++, if "int a = 3; int* p = &a;", then why is "const int* &pp = p" not allowed, but "const int* const &pp = p" is allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, constants

In C++, if:

```
int a = 3; 
int* p = &a;
```

then why is

```
const int* &pp = p;
```

not allowed, but

```
const int* const &pp = p;
```

is allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `const int* &pp = p;`, `p` has to be converted to `const int*` implicitly at first. But the converted `const int*` is a temporary, which can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const (like `const int* &`).

Temporary could be bound to lvalue-reference to const (like `const int* const &`) (and rvalue-reference), so `const int* const &pp = p;` works fine. And the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime of the reference `pp`.

Answer (score 1):

when the const on * left,the const modifier the point dest,when the const on * right,the const modifier point, and you question,the addr of local var shoule be const.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the first conversion is not allowed is that it (subtly and unintuitively) breaks const-correctness. There's a discussion [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion). In short, the problem is this:

```
const int x;
int* p;
const int** q = &p;
*q = &x;
*p = 3;
```

If the third line was valid, the fourth line would set `p` to point to `x` (because `*q` is `p`), so `*p = 3` would modify `x`, even though `x` is `const`.

The same problem occurs when the top-level modifier is a reference rather than a pointer.

You have to go all-or-nothing when modifying `const` qualifiers in multi-layered pointer types.